Need help lighting object in EEVEE
When I try to light this object, small dots of light are only visible. I have ray tracing enable and I just what to get smooth lighting to occur. Any suggestions?





Make a cube, and edit it to make it surround your model. Then in object mode, look its dimension in the sidebar, near the scale values. What are the dimensions? Then, what are your light's size and power properties?

After surrounding the model with a cube, it appeared to be 18 meters in size, which was unexpectedly large. I had to increase the light source to approximately 116.7MW to properly illuminate the model.
